# How to get the style object of a Row in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I need to get the style object for a row in ag-grid without using

```
document.querySelector(`[row-index="${rowIndex}"]`).style
```

Is there a way to get it from the `RowNode` or anything else?

Comment: Please check this page.. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the code in your question. No you can't. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f011ffb0ad989acc9e43c9eb075c98e01e264668/community-modules/core/dist/es6/rendering/row/rowComp.js#L917-L920). They don't save any styles objects internally.

```js
RowComp.prototype.postProcessStylesFromGridOptions = function () {
    var rowStyles = this.processStylesFromGridOptions();
    this.eAllRowContainers.forEach(function (row) {
        return addStylesToElement(row, rowStyles);
    });
};
```

And here is the definition of `addStylesToElement()`. As you can see the `styles` is applied directly to the DOM element.

```js
export function addStylesToElement(eElement, styles) {
    if (!styles) {
        return;
    }
    Object.keys(styles).forEach(function (key) {
        var keyCamelCase = hyphenToCamelCase(key);
        if (keyCamelCase) {
            eElement.style[keyCamelCase] = styles[key];
        }
    });
}
```